# Dynamic survey app DB structure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am creating a app the creates surveys. But I am struggling in the database structure.

```
My Tables:
Surveys:
- id;
- user_id;
- title;
- status;

Questions:
- id;
- survey_id;
- label;
- input_type;
- options;
- order;
```

My only issue is that i need to be able to create some kind of cascading or populate feature.

**For Example :** Imagine that i have a question (radio button) where the answer have 2 options, "`yes`" or "`no`", but  in case that the user selects "yes" for example it appears another question.

How i would structure my tables?

Answer (score 0):

To have the chaining feature you could use self relations within questions table. In you migration add this.

```
$table->integer('questions_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('questions_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
```

Then in your Model you can do following.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'questions_id');
    }
}
```

Then if you select 'yes' pass the `question id` and you can query like this.

```
$questions = Question::with('children')->find($questionId);
// $questions has related questions
```

You can use this approach as the base and improve upon it.

**Edit**

As per your comment you would need a `answer_question` pivot table with `answer_id` and `question_id`.

In Answer model
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'answer_question');
    }
}
```

And when you query

```
$answerWithQuestions = Answers::with('questions')->find($answerId);
// $answerWithQuestions has related Questions
```

Comment: Hello Gayan, thanks for your feedback, but how i would relate the new questions based on the  answer of the user? For example i have 4 available  input  check box type, and a user selects for example the answer of the second checkbox, based on that answer give another question, i would i structure this situation? I think i would need one more table to create this type of relations i think.